# Show that $\mathscr{C}_{X,a}\cong\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}/ I(X)\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, sheaf-theory

Let $X\subset A^n$ be an affine variety, and let $a\in X$ be a point. Show that $\mathscr{C}_{X,a}\cong\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}/ I(X)\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}$, where $I(X)\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}$ denotes the ideal in $\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}$ generated by all quotients $\frac{f}{1}$ for $f\in I(X)$.

$\mathscr{C}_{X,a}$ is the stalk of $\mathscr{C}_X$ at $a$ and $\mathscr{C}_X$ is the set of all regular functions on $X$.

This problem is very confusing to me, since I don't quite understand the concepts of sheaf and especially stalk.

I should define a map from $\mathscr{C}_{X,a}$ to $\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}/ I(X)\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}$:

$$\frac{g+I(X)}{f+I(X)} \mapsto \frac{g}{f} + I(X)\mathscr{C}_{A^n,a}$$

where $f+I(X),g+I(X)\in A(X)$ and $f(a)\neq 0$. I should then prove it is well-defined, injective and surjective. But I cannot continue because I am not sure what right hand side is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: One clarification: $\mathscr{C}_X, \mathscr{C}_{A^n}$ are ring of regular functions (i.e. $\mathscr{C}_X= k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I(X), \mathscr{C}_{A^n}=k[x_1, \dots ,x_n]$ ) or sheaf of regular functions?

Comment: @Krish: Thank you for your reply! I believe they are rings(or K-algebra) of regular functions. Although I don't understand the difference. I am not sure about this concept sheaf yet. If you could explain a little, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: $\mathscr{C}_X= k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I(X).$ Let $P$ be the prime ideal of $k[x_1, \dots ,x_n]$ corresponding to the point $a \in X.$ Then $\mathscr{C}_{X,a}= (k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I(X))_P = k[x_1, \dots ,x_n]_P/I(X)k[x_1, \dots ,x_n]_P.$ (Here $R_P$ means the localization of the ring $R$ at the prime ideal P)

Comment: Why is $\mathscr{C}_{X,a}= (k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I(X))_P$? Isn't it $\mathscr{C}_{X,a}= (k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I(X))_{S_a}$ where $S_a=\{f\in A(X): f(a)\neq 0\}$? I think these are totally opposite sets? Thanks!